# Download zip post and get casperjs

Tags: web-applications, request, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to download all zip file from a webapp with casperjs
There is a click button to download the file but when I click with `casper.click` nothing happens.

When I click in my browser I have two requests:

[image: requests]

I am new to casperjs and don't know how to handle such requests. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the size of zip file?

Comment: @Igor it's a little zip with a xml and pdf ~100ko

Comment: https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/362

Comment: @Igor What does that link have to do with this problem?

Comment: @Vaviloff You don't know? An example + info, do you understand now or not yet?

Comment: @Igor The issue is about CasperJS not being capable of downloading LARGE files that are more than 7MB. How is this applicable here, when OP's file is about 100KB?

Comment: @Vaviloff Maybe yes, i was wrong. i don't want to deal with this issue anyway.

Comment: @Igor Please pay more attention to questions and your answers.

Comment: @PierreCapon Does the target page require authentication? Can you share a sample of your script?

Comment: @Vaviloff Yes, here is my code : https://gist.github.com/ModBrick/e94127da6eea6bedb39624e78aaf997d